# Simple question on Martingale definition

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, martingales, expected-value, filtrations

In the definition of martingales from [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingal#Definition) there are two conditions. It must be an adapted and integrable process for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

**My question is just**:
What could happen if we omit the condition that $\mathbb{E}(|X_n|) < \infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and we allow it to be $\infty$?

*My Thoughts*: Since the operator $\mathbb{E}: \chi \to \mathbb{R}$ is linear, where $\chi\subset L^1(\Omega)$ is the space of random variables. Maybe dropping the second condition could lead to this operator not to be bounded.

Many thanks

Comment: Conditional expectation is usually only defined for stochastic variables in $\mathcal{L} ^1(P)$.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen That's not quite right. The conditional expectation is defined whenever a random variable with the right properties exists. It is true that the usual condition people use that guarantees that the conditional expectation of $X$ exists is that $X \in L^1(P)$ but this is not the only condition that works - for example non-negativity of $X$ works too.